# "Dead-draw" endgame lost?

Tags: endgame, blunder

Are there examples of games between notable players where "dead-draw" endgames
 were lost ?

For examples : Both players had three connected pawns on the f-g-h-file (or 
 a-b-c file) without free pawns and the king were near the pawns and material
 was level.

Such positions are generally considered to be "dead-draw".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This game between Ponomariov and Carlsen was quite a sensation in 2010. Especially because there is no single outrageous blunder - Ponomariov is just outplayed very systematically. Alas, one has to keep in mind that it was a rapid game.

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 d5 4. cxd5 Nxd5 5. e4 Nxc3 6. bxc3
Bg7 7. Bc4 c5 8. Ne2 Nc6 9. Be3 O-O 10. O-O Qc7 11. Rb1 Rd8
12. Bf4 Be5 13. Bxe5 Nxe5 14. Bb3 Ng4 15. Ng3 Qf4 16. h3 Nf6
17. e5 Nd5 18. Ne2 Qe4 19. Ng3 Qf4 20. dxc5 Be6 21. Qd4 b6
22. Ne2 Qf5 23. cxb6 Nxb6 24. Qf4 Rac8 25. Qxf5 Bxf5 26. Rbd1
Bd3 27. Rfe1 a5 28. Nf4 Bc4 29. Rxd8 Rxd8 30. Re4 Bxb3 31. axb3 Rd1 
32. Kh2 Rb1 33. c4 Rxb3 34. c5 Nd7 35. c6 Nb6 36. Rd4 Rc3 
37. Nd5 Nxd5 38. Rxd5 Rxc6 39. Rxa5 Rc4 40. Kg3 e6 41. f4 h6 
42. Kf3 Rc3 43. Kf2 g5 44. fxg5 hxg5
45. Ra4 Kg7 46. Rg4 Kh6 47. g3 Kh5 48. Ra4 Kg6 49. Ra5 Rd3
50. h4 gxh4 51. gxh4 Rd7 52. Ke3 Rb7 53. Kf4 Rb4 54. Kg3 Kf5
55. Ra7 Rg4 56. Kf3 Rg7 57. Ra5 Rg1 58. Rb5 Ra1 59. Rc5 Ra3
60. Kf2 Ke4 61. h5 Ra8 62. Kg3 Kf5 63. Kh4 Ra4 64. Kg3 Rg4
65. Kf3 Rf4 66. Kg3 Kg5 67. h6 Rg4 68. Kf3 Rh4 69. Rc7 Kg6
70. Rc8 Rxh6 71. Kg4 Rh1 72. Rg8 Kh7 73. Ra8 Rf1 74. Ra2 Kg6
75. Rg2 Rf5 76. Re2 Kg7 77. Kg3 Kf8 78. Re4 Ke7 79. Kg4 Kd7
80. Rd4 Kc6 81. Rd6 Kc7 82. Rd1 Rxe5 83. Rf1 f5 84. Kg5 Kd6
85. Kf6 Re4 86. Rd1 Kc5 87. Rd8 f4 88. Kg5 e5 89. Kg4 Re3
90. Rd1 Kc4 91. Rd2 f3 92. Kg3 e4 93. Kf2 Rd3 94. Ra2 Kd4
95. Ra4 Ke5 96. Kg3 Rd2 97. Ra5 Kd4 98. Ra4 Ke3 99. Ra3 Ke2
100. Kf4 f2 0-1
```

Comment: (For what it's worth:) ​ ​ ​ According to the Lomonosov tablebases, both ways for black to take h6 on move 70 leave a draw, and the position remained drawn from then until white missed the only-drawing-move ​ 72. Kf4 . ​ ​ ​ According to the combination of those and 6-piece tablebases, black kept the win the whole way after that. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​